# Best Method to Increase TPS on PoA Blockchain

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain, genesis, scalability, poa

In creating a PoA blockchain where a high TPS is needed, how will you define the `genesis.json` configuration? There will be sealer nodes on opposite ends of the globe with ~ 0.1-0.2 second latency.

What problems will you encounter when you

1. Set the block time very short, to `0.5` second
2. Set the block gas limit very high, say `1,000,000,000`

If the block gas limit is `1,000,000,000` and there are 3 transactions with gas limits `999,999,999`, `2` and `1`, which transactions will be included in that block? If the block gas limit fixed in the `genesis.json`, or does it change dynamically?